# Python library for generating HTML representation of directory hierarchy (like "tree" on Linux)

Tags: library, html, python, directories

`tree` command on Linux generates visual hierarchy of files and directories, for instance:

```
/var/log % tree
.
+-- anaconda.ifcfg.log
+-- anaconda.yum.log
+-- audit
+-- boot.log
+-- btmp
+-- ConsoleKit
¦   +-- history
+-- cron
+-- cron-20151227.gz
+-- dmesg
+-- httpd
¦   +-- access_log
¦   +-- access_log-20150329.gz
¦   +-- access_log-20150405
¦   +-- error_log
¦   +-- error_log-20150329.gz
¦   +-- error_log-20150405.gz
¦   +-- error_log-20150412.gz
¦   +-- error_log-20150419
+-- iptables.log
+-- jenkins
¦   +-- jenkins.log
+-- lastlog
+-- maillog
```

Is there any library for Python that would do something like that, but that would render (decent) HTML?

Comment: subprocess.call(['tree', '-d', '/path/to/directory'])

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961378/how-to-generate-an-html-directory-list-using-python) Stack Overflow questions accepted answer uses the [Flask](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask) Library and Jinja2 to do exactly what you are asking for using html tables - you could play with the template to get something better looking by setting borders, etc.